# How to read from an XML and display in a textbox and label in a Winform

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I am creating a survey application and am having trouble reading from the XML file I wrote to display splash text inside of my splash form and questions in the actual survey form.

I am writing my questions and answers in an XML so that the program can be reused by simply creating a different XML and reading from that rather than hard-coding the questions and answers.  Here is my XML structure:

```
<questions>
    <splashText>
        <text>Splash text displaying information and purpose of the survey goes here</text>
    </splashText>

<question>
    <type>ComboBoxControl</type>
    <text>Blah blah blah?</text>
    <choices>
        <choice>Answer 1</choice>
        <choice default="true">Answer 2</choice>
        <choice>Answer 3</choice>
        <choice>Answer 4</choice>
    </choices>
    <Required>true</Required>
</question>
..
..
</questions>
```

**How can I get my program to read from my XML and put the splash text into a textbox on my splash form?**

Comment: Use WPF instead. It's much better at the sort of data binding you want. With WinForm you have to do it ALL manually.

Comment: Also. Consider using DataContractSerializer for your serialisation to and from xml.

Comment: Hey Aron, thanks for the replies.  I am about to start another project using WPF as soon as this one is done but I'd like to be able to do it both ways.  This question is more about helping me grasp the concepts and see how it can be done in this particular way.

Comment: I think I've found a way to narrow down my question.  Is it better to edit this one or create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, I haven't tested this but some healthy debugging would probably point out that your parsing code is flawed. I think this might fix it, but you should really look at your XDocument queries in an immediate window while debugging to see if you're getting what you expect.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\..\Survey.xml");

var questionList = xDocument
                       .Element("questions")
                       .Elements("question")
                       .Select(elem => new Questions
        {
            QuestionType = elem.Element("type").Value,
            QuestionText = elem.Element("text").Value,
            SplashScreenText = elem.Element("splashText").Value,
            Choices = elem.Element("choices").Elements("choice").Select(ch =>
                   new Choice
                   {
                       AnswerChoice = ch.Value
                   }).ToArray()
        }).ToList();
```

Edit:
Of course, taking a second look, I notice that your winforms code is never calling in to the XMLParser, and XMLParser isn't actually returning the list of Questions objects. You're going to need to do that before you can display anything.

Comment: I'll take a look Domenic.  I realize it is flawed that's why I've posted here.  I've never done this before and I figure this would be the perfect place to gain some knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Sure thing... When I first looked, it seemed obvious that there was a parsing flaw, but then I noticed more problems. I believe you could probably arrive at a more precise question once you dig a little deeper into where the failure is.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am very new to XML and this is my first project using it directly.  I realize that I forgot to call the parser from my actual splash form, but aside from that, do you have any tips for returning the list of questions?  Any links you think are helpful for this would be great too.

Comment: I chose this as my answer because the thinking and research I did after reading the comments and answer here got me to solve my problem.  Thanks again Domenic!

Answer (score 0):

Use a strong-types model instead of an anonymous class to read the XML and then bind your UI using a [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern. It will much easier and it will make maintenance easy.

So, when you start the application (or you hit a Refresh button), you read from the XML file(s) and create models (objects) based on what is read. You can store those questions in a static class or a singleton.

After that, from your Windows Forms, you simply access the right model and link it as required manually or using a DataBinding.

I had something similar to do in Java and this is how I resolved it. However, I used a MVC pattern instead, but MVC and MVP are really similar.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you haven't done that from the UI- Register to the splash_load event
2. Add a label (call it lbl) to the splash form and set its text when the reader gets to the splash text element.

Comment: Could you provide an example for #2?

Comment: After if (reader.Name == "splashText") you should set the label text with the reader's value

Comment: Gotcha!  I just looked up a great resource and found a few of the things I found were missing.  Thanks for assisting!